# DataTable Warning - Can not reinitiliaze DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to initialize a DataTable on Ajax Success. It works fine for first time but won't work again unless I refresh the page.

JS Function:

```
this.summaryReport = function()
    {
      crsf = $("input[name=csrftestname]").val();
      searchClients = $("#searchClients").val();
      $('#loadingmessage').show();
      $.ajax({
        url: url+"query_report_summary",
        type: "post",
        cache: false,
        data: {"csrftestname": crsf, searchClients: searchClients},
        success: function(query_result)
        {
          var data = $.parseJSON(query_result);
          $('#example').DataTable( {
            data: data,
            columns: [
            { data: "name" },
            { data: "location" },
            { data: "source" },
            { data: "contact" },
            { data: "number" },
            { data: "status" }
            ]
          } );
          self.reportSummary(data);
        },
        complete: function()
        {
          $("#reportSummaryForm")[0].reset();
          $('#loadingmessage').hide();
        }
      });
    }
```

Error i am getting is - DataTable Warning - Can not reinitialize DataTable.

HTML:

```
<form role="form" class="" id="reportSummaryForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>" value="<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>">
            <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
                <input class="form-control input-sm" type="text" id="searchClients" name="searchClients" placeholder="">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" data-bind="click: summaryReport">Search</button>
                </span>
            </div>
        </form>

<table id="example" class="display" width="100%"></table>
```

Comment: Do you have any clue about the meaning of 'reinitialize'?

Answer (score 1):

Create your dataTable upfront, in the outer scope:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  columns: [
    { data: "name" },
    { data: "location" },
    { data: "source" },
    { data: "contact" },
    { data: "number" },
    { data: "status" }
  ]
});
```

In summaryReport, `clear()` the table and `add()` the new rows, one by one. Below I am also setting the `dataType` so conversion of the response not is needed. All is under the assumption that you really get valid JSON back in the reponse that holds an array of items on the form specified in `columns` :

```
$.ajax({
  url: url+"query_report_summary",
  type: "post",
  cache: false,
  data: {"csrftestname": crsf, searchClients: searchClients},
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    table.clear()
    data.forEach(function(row) {
      table.row.add(row)
    })
    table.draw()
  }
  ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The error `Can not reinitialize DataTable` is clearly stating, that there is already a datatable initialized for this element.

You would habe to destroy the datatable after each successfull ajax-call and initialize it as a new one.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
```

should be replaced by

```
dtExample.destroy();
dtExample = $('#example').DataTable( {
```

`dtExample` has to be added as a global variable outside of your function to have access to it when performing later ajax calls.

To avoid all this you could have a look into serverside processing abilities of datatables explained in the examples section [here](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/index.html)

Comment: Thanks. I understand that my way of doing this is not very much correct. I have modified my questions with more details. Basically, I have a form which accepts a single input and on click of submit button a ajax request in initiated. Ajax request pass the input to php and gets a JSON_ENCODE response. I want my example table to be updated with that response.